# How can I get latest version from Monticello in Smalltalk?

Tags: version-control, smalltalk

I am looking for the 'svn update' of the Monticello version control system. I use the browser to search for new mcz packages, but I want to be able to do it with a script.

Comment: Installer worked, but got some deprecation warnings while loading it in Pharo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that most easiest way will be to use Installer.
If its not included in your image, do this first:

HTTPSocket httpFileIn: 'installer.pbwiki.com/f/LPF.st'.

this script will install a so-called Level Playing Field
(read more here: http://installer.pbwiki.com/LevelPlayingField)

next step is quite simple:

Installer monticello http: 'http://www.squeaksource.com';
project: 'Seaside';
install: 'Seaside-core'

you can look at usage examples here: http://installer.pbwiki.com/Installer

Answer (score 3):

The step:

Installer monticello http: 'http://www.squeaksource.com'; project: 'Seaside'; install: 'Seaside-core'

can be abbreviated to:

Installer ss project: 'Seaside29'; install: 'Seaside-Core'.